# Find the nearest point of border in a square

Tags: java, geometry

I am creating a game. The players of the game must remain within the square. I'd like to notify them of their distance to the nearest point in the square's perimeter, and stop them leaving it if the distance becomes 0.

I need to find the distance of a given point from it's nearest point to the border.

I have a square. The center of this square is at (0, 0). This means that the top right corner is at (1/2 of side, 1/2 of side) and the bottom left corner is at (- 1/2 of side, - 1/2 of side). As the map shrinks throughout the game, I must keep this value abstract.

Given a point, X and Y, how would I go about finding the nearest coordinate point so that I can measure the distance from it?

Psuedocode or Java answers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @JoeC Actually, this is for a game I am creating. Players must remain within this square, and I'd like to notify them of their distance to the border, and prevent them leaving it if distance becomes too low.

Comment: OK.  Much of it still applies though.

Comment: If (X, Y) is any coordinate, what do you mean by "the nearest coordinate point"?  The nearest corner of the square?

Comment: @AlessandroScarlatti The nearest point of the border of the square isn't necessarily the corners of it, it could be a point along the sides.

Comment: @RobertC - In fact, it will never be a corner for points inside the square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above solution seems overly complicated.

The first thing to notice is that the shortest distance from any edge to the point is always going to be a line adjacent from that edge to the point.  So I would calculate the distance from each edge at all times, and then select the shortest one to display.  That should be an easy calculation.

smallest distance from top edge:  (w*1/2) - yposition

smallest distance from left edge:  xposition - (-w*1/2)

smallest distance from right edge:  (w*1/2) - xposition

smallest distance from bottom edge:   yposition - (-w*1/2)

w is the total width of the square.

Does that seem right?  You get the idea.  You want all the distances to be a positive number, which I think the above accomplishes, but could be wrong.

Comment: Do you mean (1/2) as in half the length of the side, or actually 1/2 ?

Comment: 1/2 the length of the side.

Comment: So, since your square is shrinking, you would do 1/2*w and w is the width of the square.

Comment: So your top left corner is actually at 1/2, 1/2 and not -1/2, 1/2?

Comment: Yeah, it is actually -1/2, 1/2, I put it wrong in the original post. I tried what you put, using Math.min() I get a negative distance.

Comment: Look at left edge for instance.  maybe you have x coordinate of -1/5 (Which is inside the triangle).

Distance should be -1/5 - (-1/2) which is equal to 3/10.  Which one seems to be negative?  I edited my post like 50 times, I think the current one should work in all cases.

Comment: At X:-247 and Z:-517 I get 2517, 1653, -1653 and -2517, when the square is 4000x4000, meaning half is 2000.

Comment: I think you got some stuff missing.  I did find an error with the right edge calc.  But this is what I got:

Comment: left edge:  2247

right edge:  4473

top edge: 2517

bottom edge:  1483

Comment: I go to X -3990 and Y -3990 in the square, which should be the bottom left corner, and I'm -1970 away from the border!

Comment: x=-3990 and y=-3990 is outside of the square.  x=-1990 and y=-1990 is just inside the lower left corner of the square.  Any negative distance would mean you are actually outside of the square.

Comment: Oh yeah, duhh! My bad, been thinking about this too much so all the numbers just merge together into confusion. That seems to have solved it, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  Accept my answer :P

Comment: The "above solution" (mine, which is now below) is overly complicated? Isn't that only because I dealt with the general case, that the point could be outside the square? If you look at my description for when the point is in the square (case 5), it's basically identical to yours, is it not?

Comment: Yeah, the explanation is overly complicated.  You seem like a very smart guy, but you over complicated this one.  Simple is always best.  And yeah, we both have the same solution inside the square.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that your square is aligned with the coordinate axes. (If not, first rotate the entire problem). Then divide the plane into nine parts: inside the square, above and left of the square, directly above, etc.:

```
        .      .
        .      .
        .      .
        |      |
     1  |   2  |  3
...-----+------+-----...
        |      |
     4  |   5  |  6
        |      |
...-----+------+-----...
     7  |   8  |  9
        |      |
        .      .
        .      .
        .      .
```

Then classify your point by comparing coordinates with the lines that form the square. If the point falls in regions 1, 3, 7, or 9, then the closest point on the square is the corresponding vertex. If it falls in regions 2, 4, 6, or 8, the closest point is the projection onto the corresponding side. (Just replace the appropriate coordinate in the point with the coordinate of the side.) In region 5, you have to decide which side is closest. This can be done by simple subtraction of the appropriate coordinate. Once the closest side is identified, substitute the coordinate and you're done.

Since region 5 is the most complicated (and most relevant to your question), here's how I'd do it:

Let the point have coordinates (X, Y) and the sides of the square be at coordinates y = Y<sub>top</sub>, y = Y<sub>bottom</sub>, and similarly for x. Then compare |X - X<sub>left</sub>|, |X - X<sub>right</sub>|, |Y - Y<sub>top</sub>|, and |Y - Y<sub>bottom</sub>| to decide which is closer. Say that it's the top. Then the closest point on the square is (X, Y<sub>top</sub>) and the distance between the point and the side is just |Y - Y<sub>top</sub>|

In my narrative description, I just used absolute values for region 5, but you can avoid taking absolute values by reversing the appropriate subtractions. (Which ones to reverse depends on how your coordinate axes run.) I also ignored the issue for classifying the point. You just have to be consistent about signs everywhere.

Comment: That's much simpler than other answers elsewhere! Thanks for the answer, appreciate it :)